# why should we not include the last array element in sprintf?

Tags: c++, c

I have a code shown as below, the last statement works only if I use l_plates[i]. In the below case it throws an error "passing argument 1 of 'sprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast"
What if I need another for loop for N too. Should I use an extra element if I use sprintf?
please explain. thanks in advance.

```
char type, letters[4], digits[5];
char l_plates[M][N];

for (i=0; i<M; i++) {
    scanf(" %c", &type);
    scanf("%3s", letters); 
    scanf("%4s", digits); 
    sprintf(l_plates[i][N], "%s %s %c", letters, digits, type);
}
```

Comment: The type of `l_plates[i][N]` is a char, but `sprintf()` wants a `char *` in the first parameter. Furthermore, reading `l_plates[i][N]` is reading beyond the array boundary.

Comment: Use `&l_plates[i][0]`.  If you use 'N' you are at the end of the buffer.

Comment: sprintf needs a pointer to the memory where the output needs to be written. What you're passing is the (N+1)th element in the 2-dimensional character array to sprintf. Not the ith buffer. To fix your code, use `sprintf(l_plates[i], ....);`.

Comment: Thanks all for your response."The variable l_plates is a one dimensional array of strings of length N" then what is the "i" for? is it a single dimensional array of length i or N.so if I wanted to have 2 loops should I declare another array element like l_plates[i][N][P]?

Comment: and by the way, it compiled without any errors even if I dont have char *.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems here. First, the first argument of sprintf should be a `char*`, not a `char`, which is what you're sending to it.

Secondly, an array of size `N` is indexed from `0` to `N - 1`. By trying to access element `N`, you're stepping outside of the array. The last element is `[N - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `sprintf` line, the expression `l_plates[i][N]` refers to a single char, and you're trying to write to it a whole string.

The variable `l_plates` is a one dimensional array of strings of length `N` (or a two dimensional array of chars).

If you need a two dimensional array of strings, then you need to define `l_plates` with something like this:

```
char* l_plates[M][N];
```

and then *malloc* those strings accordingly.

Comment: Thanks all for your response."The variable l_plates is a one dimensional array of strings of length N" then what is the "i" for? is it a single dimensional array of length i or N.so if I wanted to have 2 loops should I declare another array element like l_plates[i][N][P]?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the declaration of `l_plates`:

char l_plates[M][N];

This says that `l_plates` is an array of `N` arrays of `M` characters. Another way to think of this is as a two-dimensional array of characters.

So what is the type of `l_plates[i][N]`? It's a `char`! In other words, it is a single symbol. However, `sprintf()` requires a `char*` as its first argument. This is why you get a compiler error with your above code.

On the other hand `l_plates[i]` is an *array* of `char`s. C and C++ can both convert this array to a `char*`, so the compiler won't complain.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `l_plates[i]` is a string whereas `l_plates[i][N]` is a single character, albeit an out-of-bound one (because `N-1` is the last character).

That said, you might be better off with `snprintf()`:

```
snprintf(l_plates[i], N, "%s %s %c", letters, digits, type);
```

This makes sure you don't overflow your character array.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up about how pointers and arrays work in C.

`l_plates[i][N]` actually refers to a `char`, so it won't even compile; sprintf expects a `char*` to where it will write the output. `l_plates[i]` has type `char[N]`, implicitly convertible to `char*`, pointing to the beginning of the inner array. Giving that as argument to sprintf makes it do what you probably want.

By the way, with `l_plates[i][N]` you're accessing the inner array at an illegal offset. The offset to a size N array should be between 0 to N-1. C/C++ will not necessarily complain about this at runtime, but it's almost always a bug. In this case `l_plates[M-1][N]` does point outside the memory allocated for `l_plates`.